# Php code executing the error line while fetching data for a login page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, sql-insert

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM telecomt_user WHERE email='$email'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if ($row['password'] == md5($upass)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php

    }
}
?>
```

This is my code for fetching data from database to let the user to log in by email and password. My table name is "telecomt_user".

```
<form method="post">
    <table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" name="btn-login">Sign In</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="register.php">Sign Up Here</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

And this my html form code. The code works fine in localhost but when I uploaded it to my server it does not work. It always executes this line:

```
<script>alert('wrong details');</script>
```

Is it problem in my database? But I am using the same name and pattern what I used in my localhost and also my sign up form works with the same database. My "dbconnect.php" file is also okay. What is the problem?

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5, and COMPLETELY REMOVED in PHP 7.  The reason for this is the mysql_* functions were no longer maintained, were out of date, only intended to work with versions of mysql that have been end-of-lifed, and horribly insecure.  You need to switch to a more modern mysql interface library.

Comment: if you put $email=$_POST['email']; and the pass too; what you got ?

Comment: what can I use instead of mysql_*.Please suggest me

Comment: use `var_dump($_POST)` on the top of your code to make sure you get the form, and post the content of `dbconnect.php` file as well. You should also have a `var_dump($row)` to make sure your query actually works.

Comment: if I put $email=$_POST['email']; and the password too I got the same line executing error : wrong details.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs for the *actual* error? You're making an assumption the query is working. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: When I change my mysql text type from VARCHAR to TEXT, It started working

Answer (score -1):

instead of $row['password'] , can you try to type the column of the password in the string, for example $row[0] (if password column is the first column).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to put break point in each condition like

```
if(your condition){
  echo "something";exit;
}else{
  echo "nothing";exit;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Better to do checking on query only email and password

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM telecomt_user WHERE email='$email' AND password='md5($upass)'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Now condition login or not

```
if(count($row)>=1){
//login
}else{
// credentials wrong message
}
```

Comment: $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM telecomt_user WHERE email='$email' AND password='md5($upass)'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if(count($row)>=1)
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
 else {....}    

used in this way now it is not showing error line but does not log in. It remains in the same page index.php but it supposed to go to home.php

Comment: ob_start(); please keep these tag in top of the document.It will definately redirected for sure.